# Module includes ibm-web-bnd.xml and ibm-web-ext.xml files. How do I show an Error.jsp file when error 401, 404 etc. happen?

Tags: java, websphere

I am working on an application that has a module that contains the following

[ibm-web-bnd.xml and ibm-web-ext.xml files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGALU.png)

I'm trying to show an error page as a fix for CWE 345.
I have tried to add an ErrorPage and web.xml to the WEB-INF that calls the ErrorPage.jsp when an error occurs

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <error-page>
        <!-- Missing login -->
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <!-- Forbidden directory listing -->
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <!-- Missing resource -->
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <!-- Uncaught exception -->
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <!-- Unsupported servlet method -->
        <error-code>503</error-code>
        <location>/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

This did not work.
I also tried adding the above code to the ibm-web-bnd.xml and ibm-web-ext.xml files.
And I tried

```
<application location="Parent.ear">
    <web-ext moduleName="public" default-error-page="ErrorPage.jsp"/>
</application>
```

Nothing has worked.

Any suggestions on how to get an error page to display for the module above would really be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I had  but didn't enter it correctly and it was ignored by the code snippet.

Comment: This might be a silly observation - but you did not state if this is the whole `web.xml` file. If it is, then it's not syntactically correct. You need to close the `<web-api>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem.
The pom file in the module was ignoring everything in the WEB-INF folder.
I think that the module is not used at all but when I removed it the application didn't work.
The solution was to ignore everything in the WEB-INF except the web.xml file.
This resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, it looks like you're doing everything correctly. The only thing that looks incorrect to me is that you are not closing the `<web-app>` tag. Try closing the tag with `</web-app>`

Also, remember that you can declare JSP pages error pages directly from inside the JSP page.

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true"%>
```

And then you can forward your users to that page with this page directive:

```
<%@ page errorPage="error.jsp"%>
```